# Find Taylor's expansion around $ x=2$ for the function $f(x)=x^5+x^4+2x+1 $

Tags: real-analysis

> Find Taylor's expansion around $ x=2$ for the function $f(x)=x^5+x^4+2x+1 $

**My try:**
$$f(2)=53$$
$$f^{(1)}(x)=5x^4+4x^3+2 \Rightarrow f^{(1)}(2)=114$$
$$f^{(2)}(x)=20x^3+12x^2 \Rightarrow f^{(2)}(2)=208$$
$$f^{(3)}(x)=60x^2+24x \Rightarrow f^{(3)}(2)=288$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)=120x+24 \Rightarrow f^{(4)}(2)=264$$
$$f^{(5)}(x)=120 \Rightarrow f^{(5)}(2)=120$$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=0, n\ge6 \Rightarrow f^{(n)}(2)=0$$That is why I have: $$f(x)=53+114(x-2)+\frac{208}{2!}(x-2)^2+\frac{288}{3!}(x-2)^3+\frac{264}{4!}(x-2)^4+\frac{120}{5!}(x-2)^5$$ I checked this answer in Mathematica and I get that this is true. 
However I also checked diagrams for $f(x)=x^5+x^4+2x+1 $ and $f(x)=53+114(x-2)+\frac{208}{2!}(x-2)^2+\frac{288}{3!}(x-2)^3+\frac{264}{4!}(x-2)^4+\frac{120}{5!}(x-2)^5$ and I get that there are the same when $x\ge2$.
**Why this diagrams are different?** I think that these diagrams should be the same in all domain.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @StanTendijck Why these diagrams are different, I think that should be the same and I wonder if I made a mistake

Comment: Do you have links? What do you mean by diagrams? Their graphs?

Comment: @Clayton Yes, their graphs and there are here: https://i.imgur.com/imNWrIl.png

Comment: @MP3129 are you sure you wrote the right formula in the computer? Because they are equal... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+53%2B114(x-2)%2B%5Cfrac%7B208%7D%7B2!%7D(x-2)%5E2%2B%5Cfrac%7B288%7D%7B3!%7D(x-2)%5E3%2B%5Cfrac%7B264%7D%7B4!%7D(x-2)%5E4%2B%5Cfrac%7B120%7D%7B5!%7D(x-2)%5E5,+x%5E5%2Bx%5E4%2B2x%2B1

Comment: They look similar to me. Are you sure you don't have a typo in your equations? [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E5%2Bx%5E4%2B2x%2B1+and+g(x)%3D53%2B114(x%E2%88%922)%2B208%2F2!(x%E2%88%922)%5E2%2B288%2F3!(x%E2%88%922)%5E3%2B264%2F4!(x%E2%88%922)%5E4%2B120%2F5!(x%E2%88%922)%5E5) are the two graphs together.

Comment: Oh, I am very sorry for everyone! I checked this several times but only now I managed to notice that I wrote $\frac{208}{2!}(x-2)^3$. I apologize for littering the forum with stupid mistakes...

Comment: You can check your work by expanding $\sum_{i=0}^5 a_i(x-2)^i$, equating this to your original polynomial and then solving the resulting linear system for the unknown $a_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have polynomials on both sides of $$x^5+x^4+2x+1=53+114(x-2)+\frac{208}{2!}(x-2)^2+\frac{288}{3!}(x-2)^3+\frac{264}{4!}(x-2)^4+\frac{120}{5!}(x-2)^5$$

Thus the two sides match on the entire range of $(-\infty, \infty).$

You do not have to worry about the interval of convergence of either side.

Comment: Can you explain what it comes from? I was thinkg that when I use Taylor without rest (because in this task rest is equal $0$) then my graphs are the same and they can be different only when rest $\neq 0$

Comment: You are correct, you do not have a remainder in this case so  the polynomials are the same for every real number x.  You can check for yourself to see if they match for 6 different x-values, then they have to be identical because there is only one polynomial passing through 6 different points.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani: There is only one polynomial of degree $5$ or less passing through $6$ points (relevant for future readers).

Comment: @Clayton Thanks for the comment.